# Augmented-reality for Flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, augmented-reality

I am newbie augmented-reality in as3.I've worked as3 since about 2 years but I've never worked augmented-reality.I want to do like this swf:

http://cdn.eyewonder.com/100125/adWdrDemos/56254654/Game.swf

What is the best class or tuttorial that I will use for augmented-reality? I realy need to learn as soon as quickly augmented-reality.

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 1):

i can't see where is the Augmented Reality in your SWF example. But maybe the FLAR Toolkit will help you. It's a AS3 version of ARToolkit. It works with many Flash 3D engines like Papervision, Away3D or Sandy. You will see some example on Google.

Find the official project page here : http://www.libspark.org/wiki/saqoosha/FLARToolKit/en

And a good tutorial here : http://www.marcpelland.com/2009/03/26/getting-started-with-augmented-reality-flartoolkit/

Good luck !